# How do I reorder a points and corresponding labels in ggplot2 scatterplot by the numeric variable in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to reorder the points by the numeric variable (bc) on the y-axis in the ggplot2 chart by ascending order. My x-axis is a unique identifier (uid) for each point, however, I want the corresponding label of the point to be a different variable (name). However, the wrong labels get attached when I use the "name" variable to each point. I want the correct ones to show up, of course.

```
lopct <- ggplot(lo_pct, aes(x = uid, y = bc)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(lo_pct$uid, lo_pct$bc), y = lo_pct$bc), 
             size=2, color = "#A3A500") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = lo_pct$lci, ymax = lo_pct$uci), 
                width=0.00, show_guide = F, size = 1, color = "#A3A500") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype="solid", 
             color = "#6b5e4f", size=1) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=lo_pct$name) +
  labs(y = "Effect size (Proportion)", 
       x = "",
       title = "") +
  coord_flip()
```

I simply wrote the text for each of them, because I couldn't make anything work. However, now I want to add a tooltip with shiny R - and I'm encountering the same problem. And there I cannot specify the labels for each point.

Comment: I would be helpful if you add a sample of the data you are working on and maybe a picture of the result you want to change

Comment: Thanks - I'll do that next time. I figured out this one though. Thank anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like if I add  scale_x_discrete(limits= ""), it works.
The tooltip still won't work. For that, you just have to have unique value labels.